# Query Merge & Importrange

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to pull data from one to another sheet, but only specific columns, but it is not working.

```
=QUERY({ IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0","Pallets Total!A:B"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0","Pallets Total!F:H"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0","Pallets Total!O:Q") }, "WHERE Col2 = '"&TEXTJOIN("' OR Col2 = '", TRUE, A:A)&"'", 0)
```

I have tried to just name the different columns in the Importrange or use query itself and name the different `col`
as here:

```
=QUERY({ IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0!A:Q")}, "WHERE Col2 = '"&TEXTJOIN("' OR Col2 = '", TRUE, A:A), "select Col1, Col2, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col15, Col16, Col17",1)
```

In summery:

When I put the PalletID in this [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13yrqkfC2pBLmvfFMy5cVsQdqyp0pAKcFywr8oB1H0ZM/edit#gid=649582371) I want to have data pulled from [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0/edit#gid=2069824066)
but only the rows,

- Status
- Palett ID
- ItemDesc
- Asin
- EAN
- Units
- Unitcost
- Total Cost

This will help me to create a full article list, from what is in each Pallet

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {IMPORTRANGE("14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0", "Pallets Total!B:B"), 
  IMPORTRANGE("14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0", "Pallets Total!A:Q")}, 
 {2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 16, 17, 18}, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("14BJcO6IzT4t4ioryXivFqSEljTDPukmxTaqKV6z10U0", "Pallets Total!A:Q")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col15,Col16,Col17 
  where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A)&"'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: that was fast. But I need the all the rows. Sometimes I have different multiply stuff in one Pallet Id. So lets say, I just want to get the complete content automatically from P-0001 and P-0003.

Comment: @Guhlis answer updated